# My US visa is damaged as the passport authority clipped the corners of the old passport

Tags: visas, usa

It written clearly on the website, in the case of the passport authority clipping the corners of the old passport, you visa is damaged.

It is bit unfortunate as it was valid for five years, what I should do, applying and filling DS160 again?

Any solutions?

[image]

====EDIT====

The information bove from the embassy in Japan, now it is written clearly"Q.8 My passport has expired, but the U.S. visa in it is still valid. Do I need to apply for a new visa?
After obtaining a new passport, traveler may travel to the U.S. with the old passport with a valid visa and a new valid passport. However, both passports must be the same type, same nationality, for the same person and is the appropriate type of visa required for your principal purpose of travel.  The new passport number on the new passport and the cut of corner(s) from the old passport will not affect the validity of the visa as long as the cut of corner(s) does not damage the visa foil/sticker.  If any of the biographic information has changed between the two passports, he/she will be required to apply for a new visa. Information about U.S. visas and scheduling an appointment is available at http://www.ustraveldocs.com/hk. "

The link: https://www.ustraveldocs.com/hk/hk-gen-faq.asp#qlistgen8

Comment: On which website?  In my experience, passport authorities clipping the corners of the old passport only include the covers and the identification page, leaving the visa pages intact along with any visas on those pages.  Is that not the case here?  Did they actually clip the visa sticker itself?

Comment: My passport containing a valid visa has expired. I've obtained a new passport. Do I need a new visa?, https://jp.usembassy.gov/visas/faq-list/general-questions-niv/

Comment: see photo, all the visa is intact, but you can see the corner is cutten

Comment: It is a clipped corner, although it didnot get the information at all, I am really exhausted

Comment: I would try to find out whether the US consulate can tell you whether the damage invalidates the visa.  But I suspect that they will tell you to get a new one.  The faq you link to does say "in any way."

Comment: Yes, it seems I have to get a new one, my worry is that going to be a completely a new decision, as this one was five years. I am really confused, now i have to go conference, should I also provide evidence, or just show them this one.

Comment: Tough situation. Visa interviews (especially USA) are to be avoided as much as possible because of the possibility of an adverse outcome. Unfortunately in your case it appears that’s the prudent thing to do.

Comment: https://www.ustraveldocs.com/hk/hk-gen-faq.asp#qlistgen8, please Q.8

Comment: @Monika While not a primary source, the information you presented is suitable for an answer.

Comment: Why not ask the embassy?

Comment: @mdd,  I am trying to call them and they said check with US protection and. customs and no one replies, I dont know how to access them.

Comment: I suspect you'll be OK since it did not damage the machine readable zone.

Comment: I think it wise enough to check up, over the phone they werenot helpful, I dont know how I can enter the embassy and ask about that, unless you have an. appointment you can, any ideas, I am afraid since the two websites contradicts each other.